# How to save a file(picture, pdf) into ibm db2

Tags: java, jpa, db2, ejb, prepared-statement

I'm trying to get my code to load a picture and save it in DB2. I'm not sure what to do next because the code below is failing. Can someone guide me on how to do this. I have generated an entity from the DB. Datatype for documentname(the actual file) is blob but when I generated the entity it appeared as byte[]. The method below are in the EJB.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOCUMENTS", schema = "PORTAL")
public class Documents { 
private int documentid;
private byte[] documentname;

@Id
@Column(name = "DOCUMENTID", nullable = false)
public int getDocumentid() {
    return documentid;
}
public void setDocumentid(int documentid) {
    this.documentid = documentid;
}
@Lob
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Column(name = "DOCUMENTNAME", nullable = true)
public byte[] getDocumentname() {
    return documentname;
}

public void setDocumentname(byte[] documentname) {
    this.documentname = documentname;
}
```

Here I'm trying to read or rather load the picture.

```
    private byte[] readImage(String filename) {

    byte[]  imageData = null;
    FileInputStream file = null;
    try {
        file = new FileInputStream(filename);
        int size = file.available();
        imageData = new byte[size];
        file.read(imageData);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (file != null) file.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return imageData;
}
```

This is basically where I think I'm loosing it.

```
public Boolean populateProfilePicture(int blobFileID, byte[] blobFIle) {

    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    int success = 0;

    String empPhotoFile = "/home/mika/Pictures";
    Documents fileTable = new Documents();
    try {
        con = dataSource.getConnection();
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Documents VALUES(?,?)");
        pstmt.setInt(1, blobFileID);
        pstmt.setBytes(2, readImage(empPhotoFile));
        success = pstmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (success>=1)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

byte[] is an appropriate type mapping for BLOB data, though you might want to look into your JPA implementation -- it may have details on how you can influence that mapping to be an InputStream etc. so you can use streaming APIs depending on the size of the files at hand.

That said, since you raw read into a byte array, it seems you might not actually care that much given how you've implemented readData().

Since you're using JPA, one might suggest that you just -- use JPA.

```
public byte[] readImage(Entity entity String filename) throws Exception {

    byte[]  imageData = null;
    try ( FileInputStream file : file = new FileInputStream(filename) ){

        int size = file.available();
        imageData = new byte[size];
        file.read(imageData);
        return imageData;
    } catch (IOException | FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw e;
    } 
}
```

This just does the same thing, but it puts the data in the JPA entity instead of trying to mess with the connection.  Should serialise to the database fine when your entity manager commits the unit of work.

**EDIT:** Here is a re-write of your populate* method as requested.  Note that I'm manually managing the transaction, and making a lot of assumptions about your entitymanager.  that stuff is a bigger/different question.

```
public void populateProfilePicture(int blobFileID, String employeePhoto) throws Exception {

    // this is about you figuring out JPA.
    EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager()
    EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
    transaction.begin()
    try {

    Documents documents = entityManager.find(Documents.class, blobFileID);
    byte[] data readImage( employeePhoto );
    documents.setDocumentname( data );
    } catch(Exception e) {
        transaction.setRollbackOnly();
        throw e
    }
    } finally {
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Iscoughlin I'm a bit lost, I find updates on the method but I don't know to relate it with the other one as it doesn't have the return type. Can you help me with using that method with the other populateProfilePicture.

Comment: @Mika I edited things up a bit for clarity.  Hope that helps.